# Does std::make_shared(new Foo()) create singletons?

Tags: c++, c++11, make-shared

When `std::make_shared(new Foo())` is called, it constructs a Foo and returns a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` for the caller (viz. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)). If this is called multiple times from various objects, does it construct a `new Foo()` each time? In this case is it no different than each caller getting a single reference to a new object, acting in practicality like a unqiue_ptr?

Or does it make one `Foo()` the first time and then subsequently returning `std::shared_ptr`s to it, knowing that it will act like a Singleton of sorts (and of course deleting once the last `std::shared_ptr` is destroyed)? Is this platform specific?

Specifically a function as such:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo> makeFoo()
{
  return std::make_shared<Foo>();
}
```

Comment: It constructs a new `Foo` every time it called.

Comment: No, it will not create a singleton and it is not the same as a unqiue_ptr.

Comment: `new Foo()` and `makeFoo()` always creates a new object, so no, a singleton isn't returned. The names unique and shared only refer to the way the class can be used: `shared_ptr`s have reference counting and multiple `shared_ptr`s to the same resource can exist. `unique_ptr`s do the opposite where only one instance of the class has access to the resource.

Comment: Why don't you construct two of them and compare their addresses?

Comment: I'm actually curious as to how you came to think that `make_shared` had anything to do with singletons. There was another question that asked if `make_unique` made singletons, even though the two functions return totally different smart pointers. I'm actually wondering if there is some really badly-written C++11 tutorial somewhere spreading disinformation.

Comment: There's absolutely no mention of it in the documentation, I'm actually surprised too..

Comment: Your confusion appears to be intermingling `std::make_shared<Type>(Args...)` with `std::shared_ptr<Type>(new Type(Args...))` *Neither* create singletons. The power of shared pointers is in their assignment and/or initialization from *other shared pointers*, not just new instances. (and of course, the automatic reference counted memory management is the cat's whiskers).

Comment: @Insilico I've seen usages of make_shared being wrapped in a makeFoo() function pretty commonly. I haven't used shared_ptrs because Google's C++ style guide suggest trying to design ownership carefully using unique_ptr instead. With makeFoo() I just didn't see why a shared_ptr would be returned if you were going to be the sole owner of a newly created object. Obviously other calls to makeFoo would give you your own new Foo, thus you could just use make_unique instead. If you had a shared_ptr, you would have to pass that reference to other objects, defeating the purpose of a makeFoo function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `std::make_shared<Foo>()` will always create a new Foo object and return the managed pointer to it.

The difference to `unique_ptr` is, that you can have multiple references to your pointer, while `unique_ptr` has only one living reference to your object.

```
auto x = std::make_shared<Foo>();
auto y = x; // y and x point to the same Foo
auto x1 = std::make_unique<Foo>();
auto y1 = x1; // Does not work
```